# Return in the correct page with paginator in dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss

I've a problem...
I use a datatable with paginator and filter, if I stay in page 3 and submit a operation with commandButton, the paginator return in page 1.
I think this happen because i use a client side filter() function in oncomplete method in commandButton.

Hope somebody can help me  :) 
THANKS

This is my code:

```
<p:dataTable 
id="myDataTable"
value="#{myBean.myList}" 
var="item"
widgetVar="myWidgetVar"
filteredValue="#{myBean.myFilterList}"
paginator="true" 
rows="5"
paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
resizableColumns="true"
styleClass="noBorders"
>
....
....
....
<p:column>
<p:commandButton 
actionListener="#{myBean.myMethod(item)}" 
oncomplete="myWidgetVar.filter()"
update="myDataTable"
/>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the "first" attribute of your datatable to a backing bean:

```
<p:dataTable 
id="myDataTable"
...
first="#{myBean.firstRow}">
...
>
```

In your myBean class:

```
private int firstRow;
```

Comment: Hi Emil, I've tried with your suggestion but not work. When I invoke the method trought the commandButton the page of datatable doesn't remain in the current page but return always in page 1.